# How to fix my gridview on fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, gridview

I want to show my data to gridview using ArrayAdapter / BaseAdapter, but always stopped when I click the fragment. If show with Toast, the data can show, but if the gridview I setAdapter become force close and nothing show error notification.

This is my fragment:

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment  {
public static final String url="http://10.0.2.2/db_m_market_localhost/action/select_picture.php";
GridView gridView;

ArrayList<object_product> arrayProduk;

Context context;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.laptop_gridview, container, false);


    arrayProduk = new ArrayList<>();

    getData();

    gridView = (GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.gv);

    return view;
}

private void getData(){

    //Creating a json array request to get the json from our api
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                    //Displaying our grid
                    showGrid(response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }
    );

    //Creating a request queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    //Adding our request to the queue
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}

private void showGrid(JSONArray jsonArray){


    //Looping through all the elements of json array
    for(int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){

        arrayProduk.clear();
        object_product ob;

        //Creating a json object of the current index
        JSONObject obj = null;
        try {

            obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            //ambil data from mysql
            int id = obj.getInt("product_id");
            String name = obj.getString("product_nm");
            int hrg = obj.getInt("product_price");
            String descrip = obj.getString("product_desc");
            double brt = obj.getDouble("product_weight");
            int jmlh = obj.getInt("product_count");
            String clr = obj.getString("product_color");
            String imageUrl = obj.getString("product_img");


            //masukan ke file object_product
            ob= new object_product();

            ob.setId(id);
            ob.setNama(name);
            ob.setDesc(descrip);
            ob.setHrg(hrg);
            ob.setImgUrl(imageUrl);
            ob.setBrt(brt);
            ob.setJmlh(jmlh);
            ob.setColor(clr);

            //add to arraylist
            arrayProduk.add(ob);

            Toast.makeText(getContext(), ""+imageUrl, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();




        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //Creating GridViewAdapter Object
    GridViewAdapter gridViewAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(getContext(), arrayProduk);

    //Adding adapter to gridview
    //gridView.setAdapter(new GridViewAdapter(this.getActivity(), arrayProduk));

    gridView.setAdapter(gridViewAdapter);


}

}
```

This is my object :

```
public class object_product {
int id, jmlh, hrg;
double brt;
String nama, desc, imgUrl, color;

//buat set and get
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getJmlh() {
    return jmlh;
}

public void setJmlh(int jmlh) {
    this.jmlh = jmlh;
}

public int getHrg() {
    return hrg;
}

public void setHrg(int hrg) {
    this.hrg = hrg;
}

public double getBrt() {
    return brt;
}

public void setBrt(double brt) {
    this.brt = brt;
}

public String getNama() {
    return nama;
}

public void setNama(String nama) {
    this.nama = nama;
}

public String getDesc() {
    return desc;
}

public void setDesc(String desc) {
    this.desc = desc;
}

public String getImgUrl() {
    return imgUrl;
}

public void setImgUrl(String imgUrl) {
    this.imgUrl = imgUrl;
}

public String getColor() {
    return color;
}

public void setColor(String color) {
    this.color = color;
}
}
```

This is my adapter :

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

//Context
Context context;


//Array List that would contain the urls and the titles for the images
ArrayList<object_product> arrayProduct;
LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

public GridViewAdapter (Context context, ArrayList<object_product> arrayProduct){
    //Getting all the values
    this.context = context;
    this.arrayProduct = arrayProduct;

}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return arrayProduct.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return arrayProduct.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    //Creating a linear layout
    if(convertView == null){
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.laptop_item_gridview, parent,false);
    }

    //object_product product = object_product.getInstance();
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.img);
    TextView textView= (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.t1);
    TextView textView1 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.t2);

    object_product product =(object_product) this.getItem(position);
    //sett text
    textView.setText(product.getNama());
    textView1.setText(product.getHrg());



    //use picasso
    Picasso.with(context).load(product.getImgUrl()).into(imageView);

    return convertView;
}

}
```

my log:

```
05-21 07:20:16.960 28150-28150/com.example.jemmycalak.thisismymarket E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                       Process: com.example.jemmycalak.thisismymarket, PID: 28150
                                                                                       java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 1
                                                                                           at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
                                                                                           at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
                                                                                           at com.example.jemmycalak.thisismymarket.Adapter.GridViewAdapter.getView(GridViewAdapter.java:78)
                                                                                           at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2263)
                                                                                           at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:1044)
                                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                                                                                           at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onMeasure(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:614)
                                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
                                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1052)
                                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:590)
                                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                                                                                           at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:668)
                                                                                           at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:735)
                                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                                                                                           at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1079)
                                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
                                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
                                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
                                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
                                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
                                                                                           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
                                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
                                                                                           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
                                                                                           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
                                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1916)
                                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
                                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
                                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
                                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
                                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
                                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
                                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
                                                                                           at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote
05-21 07:20:16.960 1590-1836/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.example.jemmycalak.thisismymarket/.MainActivity
05-21 07:20:16.990 1590-1836/system_process D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 533K, 22% free 8131K/10408K, paused 9ms, total 10ms
05-21 07:20:17.010 1590-1817/system_process I/ActivityManager: Delay finish: com.google.android.gms/.stats.service.DropBoxEntryAddedReceiver
05-21 07:20:17.060 1715-1728/com.google.android.gms.persistent D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 937K, 18% free 5063K/6124K, paused 8ms, total 8ms
05-21 07:20:17.070 1590-1602/system_process I/ActivityManager: Resuming delayed broadcast
05-21 07:20:17.500 1590-1605/system_process W/ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{afe0fba0 u0 com.example.jemmycalak.thisismymarket/.MainActivity t28 f}
05-21 07:20:17.690 1748-1748/com.android.launcher V/RenderScript: 0xb7b0ece0 Launching thread(s), CPUs 2
05-21 07:20:28.150 1590-1605/system_process W/ActivityManager: Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{afe0fba0 u0 com.example.jemmycalak.thisismymarket/.MainActivity t28 f}
```

Comment: Would You please post Your crash log ???

Comment: CANNOT TRANSLATE guest DNS ip
CANNOT TRANSLATE guest DNS ip

Comment: only that,, and very make me confused

Comment: What line causes the error?

Comment: if the log error, nothink show erorr only CANNOT TRANSLATE guest DNS ip, if i set gridview to gridview.setAdapter(gridViewAdapter);, the aplication will be stoped

Comment: **Add the full stacktrace to your question. If it lacks pointers and repeats the same words over and over, add it either way**

Comment: @LunarWatcher thanks for your comment,, sorry my bad english,,

Comment: Some issue in mapping. Can you cross check the keys that you are using .. and also print the size of the ArrayList. Some issues with Mapping

Comment: i was fixed this problem thanks to you're all respons